# Are there examples using JxBrowser as a NetBeans RCP topcomponent?

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, jxbrowser

I'm working with evaluation license of JxBrowser and I'm trying to integrate it into a Java application based on the Netbeans Rich Client Platform as a TopComponent. The code compiles but the "JxBrowser" window comes up blank, are there examples of such integration, or diagnostics that can help since the JxBrowser library is not opensource and so it is hard to debug the behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the issue. How you embed JxBrowser library into this "Netbeans Rich Client Platform as a TopComponent". I suppose you use default rendering mode which is heavyweight rendering mode. Does Netbeans Rich Client Platform allow embedding heavyweight components. To check this you can try embedding java.awt.Canvas and see if it works. If Netbeans doesn't support heavyweight controls, then you can try lightweight rendering mode. Please check JxBrowser documentation at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013069

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for the link, that solved the problem. I switched to lightweight rendering mode.